# cannot resolve symbol jetbrains' error in Android studio

Tags: java, android, methods

Am getting this error on Android studio in methods annotation @NonNull
(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull )

> And then an error saying cannot resolve symbol 'jetbrains' . I tried
> to invalidate caches and restart but it still wouldn't work, any help,
> , please.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this library to your project

`implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:16.0.2'`

or for **androidx.annotation:annotation** you need to add this

`implementation "androidx.annotation:annotation:1.2.0"`